# Parse into list by row data frame pandas or nltk

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a text file which I'm reading with pandas and nltk which is just the alphabet with three colums and an & in the last position for a total of 27 characters. I want to be able to parse the rows into a list. How could I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you provide examples of the data, what code have you tried, and what's your expected result? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/6692898

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a dataframe and you just want to change each row to a list. This can be done with the following:

```
# Create an empty list 
rowlist =[] 
  
# Iterate over each row 
for index, rows in df.iterrows(): 
    # Create list for the current row 
    my_list =[rows.col1, rows.col2, rows.col3] 
      
    # append the list to the final list 
    rowlist.append(my_list) 
  
# Print the list 
print(rowlist)
```